# How can I expand the webcam´s window? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have followed this tutorial [Acquire Images from Webcams](http://es.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/usbwebcams/ug/acquire-images-from-webcams.html) but  when I make the preview of the image with 
`preview(cam)` the image appears small and i want the image in fullscreem.

I have proved with `set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])` but it doesnt work.

How can I expand the preview image? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I hope it is useful for someone

```
%%    Create a webcam object called cam
cam = webcam;
cam.Resolution = '1280x720';
dimensions = get(0, 'ScreenSize'); %your screem
figure('Toolbar','none',...
   'Menubar', 'none',...
   'NumberTitle','Off',...
   'Position', [1 1 dimensions(3) dimensions(4)], ... % Position, pixels[x, y, width, height]
   'Name','My Preview Window');
hImage = image(zeros(720, 1280, 3)); 
preview(cam, hImage);
```